# D3 VUEjs adding Attr and or call

Tags: vue.js, d3.js

I am using D3 inside my VUEjs app..

I have created a svg that loops through my data points to create multiple circles. I am struggling to get it right to have a 'call(drag)' function or add extra attributes on?

```js
computed: {
    points() {
      return this.$store.getters["drawInfo/drawCircle"];
    }
  },
  
  created() {
    var drag = d3
      .drag()
      .subject(function(d) {
        return d;
      })
      .on("start", dragstarted)
      .on("drag", dragged)
      .on("end", dragended);

    function dragstarted(d) {
      d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
      d3.select(this).classed("dragging", true);
    }

    function dragged(d) {
     
      d3.select(this)
        .attr("cx", (d.x = d3.event.x))
        .attr("cy", (d.y = d3.event.y));
    }

    function dragended(d) {
      d3.select(this).classed("dragging", false);
    }
  },
```

```html
<g>
    <svg v-for="(item, index) in points" :key="index" @click="selected(item, index)">
      <circle
        :r="item.radius"
        :cx="item.x"
        :cy="item.y"
        :fill="item.fill"
        :stroke="item.stroke"
        :stroke-width="item.strokeWidth"
      />
     
    </svg>
  </g>
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in your snippet

Answer (score 0):

```js
        d3.select(`._${item.index}`)  
          .style("stroke-width", 2)
          .style("fill", "black");
```

```html
 <circle
        :r="item.radius"
        :cx="item.x"
        :cy="item.y"
        :fill="item.fill"
        :stroke="item.stroke"
        :stroke-width="item.strokeWidth"
        :class="`_${item.index}`"
      />
```

It was actually very simple, just added a class attribute and used that to select with d3.select